# MySQL INSERT IGNORE not working

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

Here's my table with some sample data

```
a_id | b_id
------------
  1    225
  2    494
  3    589
```

When I run this query

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (a_id, b_id) VALUES ('4', '230') ('2', '494')
```

It inserts both those rows when it's supposed to ignore the second value pair *(2, 494)*

No indexes defined, neither of those columns are primary.

What don't I know?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html):

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that *duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value* in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is issued.

(my italics).

*Your* row is not duplicating "an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value" since you have no primary key nor any unique constraints.

---

If, as you mention in one of your comments, you want neither field to be unique but you *do* want the combination to be unique, you need a composite primary key across both columns (get rid of any duplicates first):

```
alter table MYTABLE add primary key (a_id,b_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't put a `UNIQUE` criteria or set a `PRIMARY KEY`, MySql won't know that your new entry is a duplicate.

Comment: I have primary key autoincrement but still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

if there is no primary key, there can't be duplicate key to ignore. you should always set a primary key, so pleae do that - and if you want to have additional colums that shouldn't be duplicate, set them as "unique".

Comment: Hmm... so how do I ignore a duplicate row without the need for a primary key? And I don't want to set a particular column as unique. I want the combination of both columns to be unique. For instance there can be a row (3, 589) and a row (3, 330) but there can't be two (3, 589)s

Comment: You need to use a multi-column unique constraint. Example already supplied by paxdiablo. This will meet your requirement. You MUST have a unique constraint if you want MySQL to handle your IGNORE request.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, after you run the insert command your table looks like this

```
1   225
2   494
3   589
4   230
2   494
```

If so, then the answer is because your table design allows duplicates.

If you want it prevent the second record from being inserted, you'll need to define the a_id column as a primary key, or a unique index.  If you do, then the insert ignore statement will work as you expect it to, i.e. insert the records, ignore the errors such as trying to add a duplicate record.